# Show that $\operatorname{Arg}(1+z) = \frac{\theta}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$\operatorname{Arg}(1+z) = \frac{\theta}{2}$, given that $z = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$.

Here is what I have attempted:

- If $z = \operatorname{cis}(\theta)$, then $z+1 = \cos(\theta)+1 +i\sin(\theta)$
- $\tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{x+1} = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)+1}$

Is the second step even correct? If so, where do I go from here?

Comment: You have to assume that $-\pi < \theta<\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)+1}=\frac { 2\sin (\theta /2)\cos (\theta /2)} {2\cos^{2}(\theta/2)}=\tan (\theta /2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\cos(2x) = 2 \cos^2(x)-1$ to get $1+\cos(\theta) = 2 \cos^2(\theta)$ and use $\sin(x) = 2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$ to conclude

$$ \tan(\arg(1+z)) = \dfrac{2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)}{2 \cos^2(\theta/2)} = \tan(\theta/2) $$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Since it is given that $ \ |z| \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ these numbers fall on the unit circle centered on the origin in the Argand plane.  The numbers $ \ z + 1 \ $ then lie on the unit circle centered on $ \ (1 \ , \ 0) \ \ . \ $  For those numbers $ \ z \ $ with $ \ -\frac{\pi}{2} \ \le \ \theta  =  \arg(z) \ \le \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ \ , \ $ the proposition is an application of the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle), since the origin is on the circumference of the "shifted" circle.  So for this case, $ \ \arg(z + 1) \ = \ \frac{\theta}{2} \ \ . $

[image]

For $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ \le \ \arg(z) \ \le \ \pi \ \ , \ $ we need to elaborate on this slightly.  In the "shifted" circle, the included angle between the radius to the point for $ \ z + 1 \ $ and the real-axis is $ \ \pi - \theta \ \ . \ $  Since the triangle with vertices at the origin, at $ \ 1 \  , \ $ and at $ \ z + 1 \ $ is isoceles, we have $$ \ \phi \ \ = \ \ \arg(z + 1) \ \ = \ \ \frac{\pi \ - \ (\pi \ - \ \theta)}{2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\theta}{2} \ \ ^{*} $$ for this case as well, with appropriate geometrical modification for $ \  \pi  \ \le \ \arg(z) \ \le \ \frac{3 \pi}{2} \ \ . $

$ ^{*} $ this is also a corollary of the inscribed angle theorem